# can't import mhx2 formated

Tags: import, makehuman

I'm using 2.77 and it doesn't seem to recognize mhx2 export files as makehuman exports can someone who has more experience please help me i have tried activating the it through user preferences and  it still doesn't
 work

Comment: Just to make sure, mhx2 isn't compatible with the .mhx add-on that comes bundled with blender. You need to install an external add-on for it. It's available at https://thomasmakehuman.wordpress.com/mhx2-documentation/.

Comment: Please keep that up for me

Comment: do you have any idea why my makeclothes doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've only recently started fiddling with MH myself, and haven't got to MC yet. But I suggest you ask a new question about it, and be specific about the problems. There are already a few questions on MC here, but not that many, but perhaps one of them solves your issues. http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=makeclothes

Comment: ok thank you i was finally able to import it

Comment: I made a video on how to properly do this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAYSW5gimME&feature=youtu.be